# Selecting an element of a certain class that also contains a certain string

Tags: jquery

I know how to select an element which contains a certain string, but how to select an element with a certain class `my_class` which *also* contains a certain string `my_string`?

Something like `$( '.myclass':contains(my_string) )`, except this doesn't work of course.

HTML:

```
<div class='sheet_today'>
  <div class='person'>
    PERSON: <span class='sheet_today_person_name'>Kevin</span>
  </div>
  <div class='parent'>
    PARENT: <span class='sheet_today_parent_name'>Ron</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='sheet'>
  <div class='person'>
    PERSON: <span class='person_name'>Ron</span>
  </div>
  <div class='parent'>
    PARENT: <span class='parent_name'>Daniel</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='sheet'>
  <div class='person'>
    PERSON: <span class='person_name'>Raph</span>
  </div>
  <div class='parent'>
    PARENT: <span class='parent_name'>Mark</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='sheet'>
  <div class='person'>
    PERSON: <span class='person_name'>Mark</span>
  </div>
  <div class='parent'>
    PARENT: <span class='parent_name'>Tom</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='sheet'>
  <div class='person'>
    PERSON: <span class='person_name'>Daniel</span>
  </div>
  <div class='parent'>
    PARENT: <span class='parent_name'>Raph</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:
    var today_parent_name = $( '.sheet_today_parent_name' ).text();
    $( '.person_name:contains( "' + today_parent_name + '" )' ).css( 'background', 'red' );

Also tried:

```
$( '.person_name' ).find( ":contains('today_parent_name')" ).css( 'background', 'red' );
```

Comment: can you try: `$( '.myclass').find(":contains('my_string')")`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax isn't quite right. You need to put `:contains` within the string of the selector, and concatenate the `my_string` value to it. Try this:

```js
var my_string = 'foo';
$('.myclass:contains("' + my_string + '")').addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="myclass">foo bar</div>
<div class="myclass">Dolor sit</div>
```

*UPDATE*

Given your updated HTML and JS example the issue is due to the spaces in your selector. This should work:

```js
var today_parent_name = 'Ron';
$('.person_name:contains("' + today_parent_name + '")').css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='sheet' id='sheet001'>
  <div class='person'>
    PERSON: <span class='person_name'>Ron</span>
  </div>
  <div class='parent'>
    PARENT: <span class='parent_name'>Daniel</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='sheet' id='sheet002'>
  <div class='person'>
    PERSON: <span class='person_name'>Raph</span>
  </div>
  <div class='parent'>
    PARENT: <span class='parent_name'>Mark</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='sheet' id='sheet003'>
  <div class='person'>
    PERSON: <span class='person_name'>Mark</span>
  </div>
  <div class='parent'>
    PARENT: <span class='parent_name'>Tom</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='sheet' id='sheet004'>
  <div class='person'>
    PERSON: <span class='person_name'>Daniel</span>
  </div>
  <div class='parent'>
    PARENT: <span class='parent_name'>Raph</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, doesn't seem to work in my code though. I added my HTML and JS in my question.

Comment: That's due to the spaces you've added to the selector - remove them. I added a working version based on your HTML to my answerr